# khan academy redirecting default URL GO lang

Tags: go, oauth, khan-academy

I want to access khan academy services, which requires authenticate such as OAuth consumer. Authentication working fine I have used following [oauth library](https://github.com/mrjones/oauth).

**Steps**

- Get request token
- Now I have a request_token. I need to have it approved by the user.

> https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize?oauth_token=t6492705587593216

[Khan academy documentation says](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Authentication)

When the user clicks the "Accept" button, they will be redirected to callback url specified by `oauth_callback` (or `/api/auth/default_callback` if a custom callback url is not provided)

```
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth/default_callback?oauth_token_secret=NmZ5nFEttE8gwnnz&oauth_verifier=gyM9xcZVtg&oauth_token=t6492705587593216
```

Here is my GO Code

```
const (
    CONSUMER_KEY  = "XXXXX"
    CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXXXXX"
)

func GetRequestToken(r *http.Request,unitAttemptID int64)(string,error){
    c := oauth.NewConsumer(
        CONSUMER_KEY,
        CONSUMER_SECRET,
        oauth.ServiceProvider{
            RequestTokenUrl:   "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token",
            AuthorizeTokenUrl: "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize",
            AccessTokenUrl:    "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/access_token",
            ExerciseUrl:      "https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/user/exercises",
        })
    callback := "http://127.0.0.1/example/index.php/khan/authorizeRequestToken"
    requestToken, u, err := c.GetRequestTokenAndUrl(callback)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err is  - ",err)
        return "",err
    }
    fmt.Println("requestToken ",requestToken)
    return u,nil
 }
```

**Problem**

It always redirect me on custom default URL. I want to redirect my own callback url.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar situation, fixed by providing the callback as a URL query.

```
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token?oauth_callback=yourcallbackurl
```